# How to Add ObjectNode to child ObjectNode as Parent using Jackson

Tags: java, json, data-binding, jackson

I want to add 2 Nodes inside of a nested structure. The first one is the initial state that I have.

```
INITIAL 

{
  "type" : "type",
  "features" : [ {
    "properties" : {
      "staticText" : "1",
      "assets" : {
        "metaData" : {
          "someMetaData"
        }
      }
    }
  } ],
}
```

I want to add "merge" and "node" object nodes like below. Then I will be having the below one.

```
DESIRED

{
  "type" : "type",
  "features" : [ {
    "merge" : {
     "properties" : {
       "staticText" : "1",
       "assets" : {
         "node": {
          "metaData" : {
            "someMetaData"
          }
         }
       }
     } 
   }
  } ],
}
```

I tried to put empty Nodes("jsonNodes") at the below code but did not work out. How can I state at 2nd nested Nodes?

```
root.with("merge").set("properties",jsonNodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"type\" : \"type\"," +
    "  \"features\" : [ {" +
    "    \"properties\" : {" +
    "      \"staticText\" : \"1\"," +
    "      \"assets\" : {" +
    "        \"metaData\" : {" +
    "          \"someMetaData\" : \"xxx\"" +
    "        }" +
    "      }" +
    "    }" +
    "  } ]" +
    "}");
```

Transformation

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "field(features" +
    "  .map(merge" +
    "    :field(properties" +
    "      .field(assets" +
    "        .map(node" +
    "          :field(metaData)" +
    "        )" +
    "      )" +
    "    )" +
    "  )" +
    ")");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "type" : "type",
  "features" : [ {
    "merge" : {
      "properties" : {
        "staticText" : "1",
        "assets" : {
          "node" : {
            "metaData" : {
              "someMetaData" : "xxx"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```